# geom_candlestick not plotting as it should on own data EDIT: Convert POSIXct to Date

Tags: r

I have some price data and I am trying to plot the `geom_candlestick` chart using the following;

Packages: `tidyquant`

```
    df %>%
     subset(date < "2019-01-24 15:30:00" & date >= "2019-01-24 14:40:00") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = close)) +
  geom_candlestick(aes(open = open, high = high, low = low, close = close),
                   color_up = "darkgreen", color_down = "darkred", 
                   fill_up  = "darkgreen", fill_down  = "darkred") +
theme_tq()
```

Which does not plot the open, high, low, close as it should.

However the following Works:

```
AAPL <- tq_get("AAPL", 
               get = "stock.prices", 
               from = "2015-09-01", 
               to = "2016-12-31")

AAPL %>%
  subset(date < "2015-11-04" & date >= "2015-10-01") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = date, y = close)) +
  geom_candlestick(aes(open = open, high = high, low = low, close = close)) +
  labs(title = "AAPL Candlestick Chart", 
       subtitle = "Zoomed in using coord_x_date",
       y = "Closing Price", x = "") + 
  theme_tq()
```

The structure of both data frames are the same. Where have I gone wrong?

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1548342900, 1548342600, 1548342300, 
1548342000, 1548341700, 1548341400, 1548341100, 1548340800, 1548340500, 
1548340200, 1548339900, 1548339600, 1548339300, 1548339000, 1548338700, 
1548338400, 1548338100, 1548337800, 1548337500, 1548337200), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), low = c(101.95, 102.1, 102.28, 102.29, 
102.31, 102.33, 102.33, 102.34, 102.34, 102.5, 102.59, 102.51, 
102.51, 102.5, 102.6, 102.59, 102.68, 102.67, 102.71, 102.8), 
    high = c(102.11, 102.29, 102.36, 102.34, 102.4, 102.35, 102.43, 
    102.42, 102.51, 102.61, 102.68, 102.59, 102.57, 102.67, 102.7, 
    102.7, 102.69, 102.83, 102.91, 102.95), open = c(102.11, 
    102.29, 102.29, 102.32, 102.34, 102.34, 102.34, 102.34, 102.51, 
    102.61, 102.59, 102.51, 102.57, 102.67, 102.7, 102.67, 102.68, 
    102.83, 102.86, 102.82), close = c(101.96, 102.1, 102.29, 
    102.32, 102.32, 102.34, 102.34, 102.34, 102.34, 102.5, 102.68, 
    102.59, 102.51, 102.5, 102.66, 102.7, 102.69, 102.73, 102.83, 
    102.9), volume = c(68.47, 55.24, 12.54, 128.77, 86.44, 45.84, 
    47.4, 31.97, 61.93, 31.02, 4.85, 33.49, 3.01, 180.48, 43.45, 
    61.53, 17.27, 34.86, 47.1, 14.61)), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: The structures are not the same: `date` in `df` is `POSIXct`, while in `AAPL` it is `Date`. Not sure if there is a simple solution to this, though.

Comment: I see. You are right. Applying - `as.Date(as.POSIXct(x$date, 'GMT'))` doesn´t return the hours either.

Comment: `format(df$date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", 'CET')` - Puts the date in the correct format I believe but it stores it as a character. Then applying this -  (   `df$date2 <- as.Date(df$date1, format("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))`  ) - removes the hour formats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things:

1) In your first code block, you have two pipes (`df %>% %>% subset()`). Make sure to clean that up.

2) If you check your subset, you'll see you're not returning any data -- hence, why no information is being plotted. For example,

```
df %>%
  subset(date < "2019-01-24 17:20:00" & date >= "2019-01-24 16:05:00") %>% View()
```

will return an empty dataframe. In the dataframe you've provided, there are no timestamps that go later than `09:15:00`, so asking for data between `16:50` and `17:20` is empty.

You can comment out your `subset()` line, and you will indeed get a plot.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have sorted point 1 out. Point 2: The data runs from `> c(min(df$date), max(df$date))
[1] "2019-01-24 14:40:00 CET" "2019-01-24 16:15:00 CET"`. I Will update the `subset` also